# Every open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a cartesian product of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, metric-spaces

I am trying to prove an assertion I made which would be greatly simplified if I can prove the following claim:

> Every open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a cartesian product of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$?

Attempt: Let $U$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the product topology.

Then $U= \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}U_j$, where $U_j$ are basis elements, i.e. $U_j=\prod_{i=1}^n U_{j,i}$ with each $U_{j,i}$ open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Thus, $U= \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}U_j= \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}\prod_{i=1}^n U_{j,i}$

If I can swap the order, then $U=\prod_{i=1}^n\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} U_{j,i}=\prod_{i=1}^n B_i$, where each $B_i$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, thus proving the claim.

Is this true? If yes, how can I justify swapping the order?

Comment: The "theorem" is false. An open disk in $\Bbb R^2$ is obviously not the product of two open sets of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: However, every open subset is *a union* of such products, simply because boxes $\prod_{i=1}^n (a_i,b_i)$ generates the topology

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I don't understand the reason for downvotes since this is still a legitimate question, but if people want this closed, I can try deleting the question.

Comment: I have not voted yay or nay, *but* you should keep in mind the comment of @jjagmath: you are trying to prove that a false statement is true, and hence your proof *must* have an error (or, of course, mathematics is inconsistent).

Comment: @LeeMosher How is that statement false? Isn't that the definition of basis? Or should that have been a possibly uncountable union?

Comment: You're right, the countable union is fine. But the statement you are trying to prove is still false. And no, you cannot swap the order of a union and a cartesian product. I'm confident you can find a counterexample in the plane, i.e. a union of two boxes that is not a box.

Comment: @approximation Same thing, didn't up nor down vote. Some people down vote immediately when they see a false statement though

Comment: That said, the quality of this post would be improved by accepting José's correct answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That statement is not true. There are open sets with the usual topology in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that are not product of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$, like balls with the usual distance. If you know about product topology that's the reason why the cartesian product of topologies is a base of the product topology rather than the product topology itself.